# Integration my application with Facebook

Tags: facebook, leaderboards

So I recently developed this game which I would like to launch into Facebook but am having a hard time figuring out how on earth do I get the basics right. Like extracting user data i.e friends playing the game. Compile a global leader board and such. Also I was wondering if I want to keep a live update on who has got the highest score on the leader board, how do I go about doing that!?

Any suggestions and links to material explaining Facebook application integration for dummies will be a great help! Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you probably know about the [Facebook API Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/). Other than that you can find various snippets and examples via Google but a lot of them still target the old Facebook API. Personally I found the API-Docs and the code-examples to be sufficient to get started, but this might vary depending on the programming-language you're going to use.

Typically you would create a server application that provides the leaderboard and live-updates to your client apps. The server-app uses the Facebook API to get user data from Facebook.

To get user data (like friends etc.) the user needs to grant your application permission to that data. You can find more information about authentication here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

**Update:** These links might also help you getting started. They target the iPhone, but should give you an overview nevertheless: [Using the FB Graph API](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app), [Getting the users profile](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)

Comment: Yep this seems to help.. Though I would rather appreciate a dummy application whose source I could study... :) (both front and backend)

Comment: That first link posted has a 'Samples' section.

Comment: +1 for the good links...i agree with the frustrations felt with most of the tutorials pointing towards the older version of the Facebook API

Comment: Hmm...how about instead of iPhone and the iOS, I'm using Google Nexus tablet PC and Android Jellybean? That will be work to?

Answer (score 1):

This page has some basic functionality explained with PHP server side. Most likely you want to rewrite those PHP scripts as they seem to be open for SQL-injections.

http://ideveloper.kodingen.com/2010/facebook-friends-leaderboard/